# Scrollbar is not working with Dumbell Chart in Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have tried to make scrollbar in Dumbell and Timeline chart with Highchart and and to achive i replaced
"https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" with
"https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js" and it is sowing bar but is is not working coming as disabled.
[Dumbell chart with scroll bar][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC0rB.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the scrollablePlotArea feature?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5ydr1ueL/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'dumbbell',
    inverted: true,
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minHeight: 800
    },
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea

Comment: i am using as  : 
 chart: {
                type: 'dumbbell',
                inverted: true,
                height:400,
                marginLeft: 280,
                spacingLeft: 10,
                scrollablePlotArea: {
                    minHeight: 800,
                    scrollPositionX: 1,
                    opacity:1
                }
            }

it is sowing unexpected behavior   height:400 is not working in this case

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on some online editor that I could work on.

Comment: Please refer link :  https://jsfiddle.net/thakurlal_pandey/gwk2xf0v/4/ 
Here we have 20 records and we need to show max 20 in chart and rest in scroll.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where the problem is, if you change the value of `minHeight` another amount of points will be renderend. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kz3voecb/ Would you like to have this value caluclated dynamically?